# How can I get a running total with mongodb aggregate framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am fairly new to MongoDB and I am playing with the aggregate framework. One of the examples from the documentation shows the following, which returns total number of new user joins per month and lists the month joined:

```javascript
db.users.aggregate(
  [
    { $project : { month_joined : { $month : "$joined" } } } ,
    { $group : { _id : {month_joined:"$month_joined"} , number : { $sum : 1 } } },
    { $sort : { "_id.month_joined" : 1 } }
  ]
)
```

The code outputs the following:

```javascript
{
  "_id" : {
    "month_joined" : 1
  },
  "number" : 3
},
{
  "_id" : {
    "month_joined" : 2
  },
  "number" : 9
},
{
  "_id" : {
    "month_joined" : 3
  },
  "number" : 5
}
```

Is it possible to also have each object contain the sum of all users that have joined since the start, so I don't have to run over the objects programmatically and calculate it myself?

Example desired output:

```javascript
{
  "_id" : {
    "month_joined" : 1
  },
  "number" : 3,
  "total": 3
},
{
  "_id" : {
    "month_joined" : 2
  },
  "number" : 9,
  "total": 12
},
{
  "_id" : {
    "month_joined" : 3
  },
  "number" : 5,
  "total": 17
}
```

Comment: The example would be a loop with only 12 iterations (12 months). :) It's not a natural fit for Aggregation, and I'd suggest you consider implementing it on the client.

Comment: Sure in this problem, it's only 12 iterations. But you can imagine a much larger problem. This is just a sample.

Comment: Again, I don't know that there's actually an efficient and practical way to do this with the Aggregation framework. As I said, it would be better to apply the running total on the client. If you're using the AF, it's going to be a limited result set anyway.

Comment: I ended up implementing on the client side. Can you explain what you mean by "If you're using the AF, it's going to be a limited result set anyway?" Thanks

Comment: The results wouldn't exceed 16MB in the aggregation framework (as that's the limit for the results)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543459/add-the-index-of-each-array-element-to-the-element-itself/19611318#19611318