# Add the "index" of each array element to the element itself

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Using the aggregation framework I want to add the index of each element inside the array to the subdocument itself.

In a later stage I'd like to `$unwind` the elements, but then I need the old index inside the myResults Array.

Current structure:

```
{ myResults : [
    { foo: "bar"
    },
    { answer: 42
    }
]
```

Target structure:

```
{ myResults : [
    { index: 0,  // <-- this should be added
      foo: "bar"
    },
    { index: 1,  // <-- this should be added
      answer: 42
    }
]
```

**Note:** I don't want to update the elements, - I just want to use the index in a later stage of the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: +1 Interesting question. But judging by the fact that [these](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17640788/390819) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16191125/390819) are still not answered, I'd say it's not currently possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to vote up this issue in [MongoDB Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/) system:

[Add option to `$unwind` to emit array index](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4588)

It provides exact functionality that you are asking for.  It is not currently scheduled for a particular future release, but that usually is influenced by how much it is needed.  Adding a note to it explaining your use case and voting on it will influence its prioritization relative to [other unscheduled aggregation framework tickets](https://jira.mongodb.org/issues/?jql=project%20=%20SERVER%20AND%20resolution%20=%20Unresolved%20AND%20component%20=%20%22Aggregation%20Framework%22&startIndex=50).